# WSDL file with undefined namespaces "ns1" and "xs"?

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, wsdl, xml-namespaces

Still pretty new to SOAP and WSDL, but I have I think a couple simple questions. I'm seeing sections like below in a WSDL file I'm using, but the namespace `ns1` isn't defined anywhere? The element `GetTransmissionSummary` is defined, but without the prefix `ns1`. So I'm not really sure why `ns1` is there and/or where it's defined? I know some prefixes like `tns` have a special meaning, but I can't find one for `ns1`.

```
<wsdl:message name="GetTransmissionSummary">
  <wsdl:part element="ns1:GetTransmissionSummary" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
```

Also, in the `<wsdl:types>` section, all of the elements have the prefix `xs` which is pretty standard in WSDL files. (`<xs:element name="GetTransmissionSummary">`) But, like above, I don't see the namespace `xs` defined anywhere. I also see import statements without a `schemaLocation` such as `<xs:import namespace="http://api.spp.org/schema/settlements/CommonReportSchema/v3"/>`, and I don't understand the purpose of such a statement. The WSDL file works fine in SoapUI and zeep though so it's not a broken file. Can anyone explain what is going on with this? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question, and provide WSDL in its entirety

Comment: I got the answer and it was somehow even dumber than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is really dumb. I was viewing the WSDL file in Firefox and for reasons that escape me it does not show namespace definitions there. When I open the file in VS Code or anywhere else, I can see them, and it all makes sense now.